# React Router's <Link> Tag Not working in Laravel 9

Tags: reactjs, laravel, hyperlink

I am running into a strange problem with the Link component from react-router-dom. I am trying to create a link with Anchor, but as soon as I put the  tag in the page shows nothing - just blank. When I remove the  tag, the page shows correctly with the content again.

I have imported Link from react-router-dom version 6.3.0. And this code is from a laravel installation.

My code -

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"
export default function App() {
    return <>
        <div>
            <h1>The main app!</h1>
            <Link to="/">Test</Link>
        </div>
    </>
}
```

Comment: Please open dev tools and read the errors in the console

Comment: My bad! I totally forgot to use BrowserRouter to wrap the Link tag! Problem resolved. Thanks.